# Angular CLI: add custom arguments in existing command

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am developing a multi-tenant system in **Angular 9** and we have different environments for each tenant. So I need to generate build for different environments of different tenants.
For ex:

```
ng build --prod --tenant=T1
ng build --configuraton=uat --tenant=T1
ng build --prod --tenant=T2
ng build --configuraton=uat --tenant=T2
```

I have already set up different configuration files for different tenants. I need to take this tenant name from command line arguments into code and apply configuration based on it. Is there any way to accomplish this kind of integration?
Any suggestions will be welcomed.
Thanks

Comment: I was reading about Angular Cli customization the other day.  I think they call the templates schematics. Yes you can do this but will need to do some homework on it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this functionality is not available out of the box with angular-cli.
You need to write either `npm script` or `shell script` to accomplish this task.

So if you want to access these tenant name in your angular application. 
You can put a placeholder global variable inside the script tag in your `index.html`
Something like -

```
...
    <script>
    window['tenantId'] = 'TENANT_ID'
    </script>
...
```

And then write a `npm script` in your `package.json`

```
...
'replace-tenant-id': 'node replace-tenant-id.js --tenant=T1 && ng build --prod'
...
```

Where `replace-tenant-id.js` would contain the logic to replace `'TENANT_ID'`

```
const fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile(index.html, 'utf8', function (err,data) {

  let formatted = data.replace(/TENANT_ID/g, process.argv[2]);

 fs.writeFile(index.html, formatted, 'utf8', function (err) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);
 });
});
```

P.S. - Please debug if there are any typo or syntactical error, as I haven't tried running this code. In similar fashion you can accommodate the configuration flag as well.

Comment: Thank you @Abhinesh
I have done some modifications based on your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

This can be done by using custom webpack builder and invoking ng serve as a child process and passing in the environment variable to the child process.

[Here is a step by step guide](https://medium.com/angular-explorer/angular-feature-flags-feature-toggle-applications-by-using-command-line-environment-variables-cca7b9e0ffb4) which explains how to accomplish this:

```
import * as yargs from 'yargs';
import { spawn } from 'child_process';
import { DEFAULT_APP_ENV } from './app-env';

const parseNgArgs = () => process.argv.filter((arg, index) => index > 1 && Object.keys(DEFAULT_APP_ENV).every(key => !arg.includes(key)));

const ngArgs = parseNgArgs();

const argv = { ...DEFAULT_APP_ENV, ...yargs.argv};

const childProcess = spawn('yarn', ['build', ...ngArgs], {
  stdio: 'inherit',
  env: { ...process.env, APP_ENV: JSON.stringify(argv) },
  shell: true,
});
```

Using this you can pass in any command-line environment variables like this and access them at runtime in your Angular

```
yarn build --tenant=T1 --logErrors --no-runtimeChecks --loggerHost="http://localhost:6000"
```